# hardcoded warning in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am getting this warning:

> hardcoded string "button name" should use @string resource

What does it mean?
Is there any problem (specially related to gps) in the app, if I leave it as it is?

Here is the button:

```
android:id="@+id/retrieve_location_button"
android:text="Retrieve Location"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: It is just a warning.. and can be ignored also.. but what it means is.. instaed  of using hardcoded values like  android:text="Retrieve Location" .. you can store this value in res/values folder and can then use..

Answer (score 2):

It means that your button's layout XML should look like:

```
<button android:id="@+id/retrieve_location_button" android:text="@string/location_text" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Where your strings.xml would have:

```
<resources>
    <string name="location_text">Retrieve Location</string>
</resources>
```

This is an internationalization and translation issue, not something that would affect the runtime of the program. You should externalize user-visible strings so that your application can be translated.